# Graphviz ANTLR String Template

Tags: antlr, graphviz

Ok, My question is how change StringTemplate toDot(Tree tree) in package org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate toDOT(Tree tree) or perhaps in another way,

My code is like this

```
DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);
```

So, it's generate the .dot file, but I wanna change the size of template

```
digraph {
ordering=out;
 ranksep=.4;
 node [shape=plaintext, fixedsize=true, fontsize=11, fontname="Courier",
    width=.25, height=.25];
 edge [arrowsize=.5]
  n0 [label=""];
  n1 [label="ANNOTATION_LIST"];
  n2 [label="package"];
  n2 [label="package"];
  n3 [label="Buat_Test_file"];
  n4 [label=";"];
  n5 [label="MODIFIER_LIST"];
  n5 [label="MODIFIER_LIST"];
  n6 [label="public"];
  n7 [label="class"];
 n7 [label="class"];
 n5 [label="MODIFIER_LIST"];
 n5 [label="MODIFIER_LIST"];
 n6 [label="public"];
 n8 [label="Gilang"];
n9 [label="CLASS_TOP_LEVEL_SCOPE"];

n0 -> n1 // "" -> "ANNOTATION_LIST"
n0 -> n2 // "" -> "package"
n2 -> n3 // "package" -> "Buat_Test_file"
n2 -> n4 // "package" -> ";"
n0 -> n5 // "" -> "MODIFIER_LIST"
n5 -> n6 // "MODIFIER_LIST" -> "public"
n0 -> n7 // "" -> "class"
n7 -> n5 // "class" -> "MODIFIER_LIST"
n5 -> n6 // "MODIFIER_LIST" -> "public"
n7 -> n8 // "class" -> "Gilang"
n7 -> n9 // "class" -> "CLASS_TOP_LEVEL_SCOPE"
}
```

I wanna change the width, height, and the edge.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

The `StringTemplate` responsible for the output is `public` and `static` inside [`DOTTreeGenerator`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr3/blob/9f16ccb717e8e03dfa69053a98ffe51718dd7b4a/runtime/Java/src/main/java/org/antlr/runtime/tree/DOTTreeGenerator.java):

```java
public class DOTTreeGenerator {

    public static StringTemplate _treeST =
        new StringTemplate(
            "digraph {\n\n" +
            "\tordering=out;\n" +
            "\tranksep=.4;\n" +
            "\tbgcolor=\"lightgrey\"; node [shape=box, fixedsize=false, fontsize=12, fontname=\"Helvetica-bold\", fontcolor=\"blue\"\n" +
            "\t\twidth=.25, height=.25, color=\"black\", fillcolor=\"white\", style=\"filled, solid, bold\"];\n" +
            "\tedge [arrowsize=.5, color=\"black\", style=\"bold\"]\n\n" +
            "  $nodes$\n" +
            "  $edges$\n" +
            "}\n");

    ...

}
```

In other words: simply change the template before printing your tree:

```java
double width = 0.5;
double height = 0.5;
Strign edge = "[arrowsize=.7, color=\"red\", style=\"bold\"]";

DOTTreeGenerator._treeST = new StringTemplate(
                "digraph {\n\n" +
                "\tordering=out;\n" +
                "\tranksep=.4;\n" +
                "\tbgcolor=\"lightgrey\"; node [shape=box, fixedsize=false, fontsize=12, fontname=\"Helvetica-bold\", fontcolor=\"blue\"\n" +
                "\t\twidth=" + width + ", height=" + height + ", color=\"black\", fillcolor=\"white\", style=\"filled, solid, bold\"];\n" +
                "\tedge " + edge + "\n\n" +
                "  $nodes$\n" +
                "  $edges$\n" +
                "}\n"); 

DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(...);
...
```

Comment: Check This out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002672/automatically-generate-image-png-in-antlr-with-graphviz